# div shifts on resizing the browser window

Tags: css, html

I am new to this site, so please bare my mistakes.
  I want to keep the third div in the same place and a scroller should appear when window   is resized instead of shifting.
  I can't use fixed width, because i want to add one more div below it...

```
 #wrapper {
float:left;
height:600px;
         }

#one {
clear:right;
float:left;
width:720px;
height:600px;
    background-color:#000;

    }

#two {
clear:right;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:300px;
    background-color:#999;

   }

   #three {
clear:right;
float:left;
width:320px;
height:300px;
    background-color:#600;

    }

   <head>
   </head>

   <body>

   <div id="wrapper">

  <div id="one">
      </div>
      <div id="two">
      </div>
      <div id="three">
      </div>

  </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Please add more information about your concrete problem, e.g. what you tried, what you expect and what does not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `#wrapper` fixed width:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 1340px; /* 720 + 300 + 320 */
}
```

Comment: thanks... but is there any other means, other then providing wrapper width...:)

Comment: @user1937847 Explain why do you need any other.